# Access VBA code to go to a specific record on another form via selecting it in a list drop down combo box

Tags: vba, ms-access-2016

I have a form with a combo box with a list of jobs located on a different form all with their own unique  record.  I would like to be able to click the drop-down of the combo box, select a specific job and then have it open the specific job record I select...  Struggling with coming up a VBA code that will do this.   Can anyone help?   Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open another form that just shows the record selected in a combo box, then you can use the control's `AfterUpdate` event, and use the "Where condition" argument of the `OpenForm` action:

```
Private Sub cboSearch_AfterUpdate()
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmData", , , "FileID=" & Me!cboSearch
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "frmSearch!cboSearch_AfterUpdate", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume sExit
End Sub
```

Regards,